# Cannot use futures in scala.js - Rhino was unable to load Scala.js class

Tags: scala, scala.js

When I am using futures in Scala.js, at least in tests, they are never executed and I cannot await them.

Given this simple test:

```
package example

import utest._
import utest.framework.{Test, TestSuite}
import utest.util.Tree

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.scalajs.concurrent.JSExecutionContext.Implicits.queue

object SomeFutureTest extends TestSuite {
  override def tests: Tree[Test] =
    TestSuite {
      'runs_future {
        val eventualString: Future[String] = Future[String] {
          "foo"
        }
        Await.result(eventualString, 5 seconds)
      }
    }
}
```

when I run `test`on the sbt console, I get:

```
JavaException: org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.ScalaJSCoreLib$ClassNotFoundException:
  Rhino was unable to load Scala.js class: ju_concurrent_locks_AbstractQueuedSynchronizer
```

when I do a nasty hack instead of `Await` like this:

```
while(!future.isCompleted) {}
```

it runs forever.

Does Await not work in scala.js? Is it impossible to use Futures and `Await` their results in tests?

EDIT: It works with `scala.scalajs.concurrent.JSExecutionContext.Implicits.runNow` instead of `queue`, but this calls the futures in a synchronous way.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `Await` does not work in Scala.js. It cannot, since it is a blocking API, and there is no such thing as blocking in a JS environment.

For this reason, testing frameworks support `Future`s in a special way, by allowing a *test* itself to return a `Future` of its execution. The testing framework is then responsible for maintaining asynchrony all the way down to eventually displaying the results of unit testing.

As [documented in its Readme](https://github.com/lihaoyi/utest#asynchronous-tests), uTest supports this. In your case, that would give:

```
TestSuite {
  'runs_future {
    val eventualString: Future[String] = Future[String] {
      "foo"
    }
    for (theString <- eventualString) yield {
      assert(theString == "foo")
      // and/or:
      theString
    }
  }
}
```

If you are more comfortable with the `map` notation, here is the equivalent:

```
TestSuite {
  'runs_future {
    val eventualString: Future[String] = Future[String] {
      "foo"
    }
    eventualString map { theString =>
      assert(theString == "foo")
      // and/or:
      theString
    }
  }
}
```